# Auto populate a textfield with the information of previous textfield

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, textfield

I have a form, which I'm using autofill using `jquery` in the first textfield. This textfield is called **"producto1"**.

What I want is that when user write the information in **"producto1"** automatically load the content in **"marca1"**, the content in this field will be loaded from my database.

This is my code:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
              <td width="545"><div align="center">
                <input name="producto1" type="text" class="textfield4" id="producto1" value="" size="65" />
              </div></td>
              <td width="385"><div align="center">
                <input name="marca1" type="text" class="textfield5" id="marca1" size="10" maxlength="5" onKeyPress="return handleEnter(event);">
              </div></td>
              <td width="385"><input name="cantidad1" type="text" class="textfield5" id="textfield2" size="10" maxlength="5" onKeyPress="return handleEnter(event);"></td>
            </tr>
</table>
```

The information that will be displayed at the **"marca1"** field will be loaded from my database, but my problem is that I don't know how to populate automatically this second field using ajax.

Answer (score 0):

```
// JS File
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#producto1").keyup(function(){
       $.post('/path-to/marca.php', 
              {
                 text: $(this).val()
              },
              function(data) {
                  $('#marca1').val(data.returns);
              }, 
              'json');
   });
});

// PHP File

$sql = $mysqli->query("SELECT marca_name 
                      FROM marca 
                      WHERE marca_name 
                      LIKE '%" . $mysql->real_escape_string($_POST['text']) . "%'");
while($row = $sql->fetch_assoc($sql))
   $returns[] = $row['marca_name'];

echo json_encode("returns" => implode(",", $returns));
```